# Dúvidas com .CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Olá. Eu tenho um tema Wordpress novo e estou tentando customiza-lo. Todos os temas Wordpress que já trabalhei sempre tem arquivos .CSS que modificamos, mas este meu tema tem arquivos .SCSS e quando modifico-os não faz efeito nenhum no tema. mesmo que eles estejam modificados no arquivo, no tema não acontece nada. Quando vou no debug do navegador ele continua aparecendo normal, mas no arquivo ele aparece modificado. Por qual motivo?

Comment: Conforme resposta abaixo, o problema de fato é o entendimento do que é um SCSS. Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Para as próximas postagens, sempre que tiver problemas em algum detalhe específico dentro do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), procure sempre postar um [MCVE] que reproduza seu problema.

Comment: Até onde eu sei vc pode escrever códigos CSS dentro de arquivos SCSS ou SASS sem problemas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Seu tema esta utilizando Sass/Scss, o qual não é interpretado pelo browser, para isso você precisa compilar seu arquivo Sass/Scss em CSS. Veja mais detalhes de como rodar e instalar aqui: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas não entendi esse negócio de compilação.